# Creating a Autocomplete search form in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

To get an idea of what I want

[image]

When the textfield is clicked, the dropdown appears with suggestions that are filtered out as the user types in the text field. The height of the box should also adjust real-time to either contain all of the items, or a maximum of 10 items.

I managed to get this somewhat working using a ComboBox, but it felt a bit rough around the edges and it didn't seem possible to do what I wanted (The dropdown doesn't resize unless you close it and re-open it).

New idea, have a text field and then show a VBox of buttons as the dropdown. The only problem is that I don't know how to position the dropdown so that it doest stay in the noral flow so it can overlay any exisiting elements below the text field. Any ideas?

Comment: There's really nothing to share at the moment. I'm still trying to figure out how to get items to position out of the normal flow before I do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do has already been implemented, and is included in [`ControlsFx`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/). It's open source, and I think it would suit you need. It looks some what like this

[image]

You can even add custom nodes to it, so that `cross` can be done too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this is for a university project so I can't use any third party libraries. I'll try reading through it as see if I can figure out how they did it.

Answer (score 3):

Please consider this **Example**, you can take the idea and apply it to your project.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SearchFormJavaFX  extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) throws Exception {
        String[] options = {"How do I get a passport",
                            "How do I delete my Facebook Account",
                            "How can I change my password",
                            "How do I write some code in my question :D"}; 

        // note that you don't need to stick to these types of containers, it's just an example
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        GridPane container = new GridPane();
        HBox searchBox = new HBox();

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        TextField text = new TextField(); 

        // add a listener to listen to the changes in the text field
        text.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(container.getChildren().size()>1){ // if already contains a drop-down menu -> remove it 
                container.getChildren().remove(1);
            }
            container.add(populateDropDownMenu(newValue, options),0,1); // then add the populated drop-down menu to the second row in the grid pane
        });

        // those buttons just for example
        // note that you can add action listeners to them ..etc
        Button close = new Button("X");
        Button search = new Button("Search");
        searchBox.getChildren().addAll(text,close,search);


        /////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // add the search box to first row
        container.add(searchBox, 0, 0);
        // the colors in all containers only for example
        container.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GRAY, null,null)));
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////

        root.getChildren().add(container);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 225,300);
        ps.setScene(scene);
        ps.show();


    }


    // this method searches for a given text in an array of Strings (i.e. the options)
    // then returns a VBox containing all matches
    public static VBox populateDropDownMenu(String text, String[] options){
        VBox dropDownMenu = new VBox();
        dropDownMenu.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, null,null))); // colors just for example
        dropDownMenu.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER); // all these are optional and up to you

        for(String option : options){ // loop through every String in the array
            // if the given text is not empty and doesn't consists of spaces only, as well as it's a part of one (or more) of the options
            if(!text.replace(" ", "").isEmpty() && option.toUpperCase().contains(text.toUpperCase())){ 
                Label label = new Label(option); // create a label and set the text 
                // you can add listener to the label here if you want
                // your user to be able to click on the options in the drop-down menu
                dropDownMenu.getChildren().add(label); // add the label to the VBox
            }
        }

        return dropDownMenu; // at the end return the VBox (i.e. drop-down menu)
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

[image]  [image]

Comment: @Alex Please copy-paste the code to your IDE and try it yourself. I know the colors are not so amazing, but that is just for example :)

Comment: This is basically everything that I want, however the problem is that the dropdown doesn't hover over everything else, so if I added another element below the text field the dropdown menu would push it down.

Comment: @Alex I re-read your comment and I see what you're talking about... Please read more about `StackPane` properties as it shall do what you want (i.e. put others elements which are under the text field in a stack pane then add and remove the drop-down menu the same way as it's at the last index). That's way in the first place I asked you to put some code. However, the functionality is achieved and what you're looking for is the structure which your question has nothing to do with!

Comment: I can't put the elements under the StackPane because I'm laying them out in a grid, and I'd have to position every element manually so they don't all sit on top of each other. This is the effect I'm going for (I did a poor job of explaining myself): [link](https://imgur.com/a/FReLP).

Comment: Also, the only questions that I asked was to do with the structure. Again, I'll take the blame for that, I was hoping that if I asked a more specific question that someone would point me in the direction of another way to do it. I probably should have asked specifically about the positioning problem though. Not that I don't appreciate what you did. Anyone that takes the time to help me is awesome! So thank you for doing that, really. It just didn't answer my question.

Comment: @Alex Thump up, no worries :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void pushEmails(TextField Receptient) {
    ArrayList<CustomTextField> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < Sendemails.size(); i++) {
        CustomTextField logo=new CustomTextField(Sendemails.get(i));
        ImageView logoView=new ImageView(new Image("/Images/Gmail.png"));
        logo.setRight(logoView);
        list.add(logo);
    }

    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(Receptient, list);
}
```

Comment: Does this use a library? CustomTextField and TextFields aren't classes as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah TextField is defaut Class of javafx.scene.control.TextField and CustomTextField is class from Control Fx library http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/